# Barcode image is not generating using barcode_encode_genbarcode function in php , it display blank barcode image

Tags: php, centos7, barcode, barcode-printing

> Barcode image is not generating using **barcode_encode_genbarcode**
> function in php , it display blank barcode image.

When I trace it out I found it gives me a blank array, which generates a barcode image

After that, I tried to install nix but not able to install nix/genbarcode in Centos 7.
It is giving me the below error:-

```
**error: File not found by glob: epel-release*rpm**

    function barcode_encode_genbarcode($code, $encoding){
global $genbarcode_loc;

/* delete EAN-13 checksum */
if (preg_match("@^ean$@i", $encoding) && strlen($code) == 13) 
    $code = substr($code,0,12);
if (!$encoding) 
    $encoding = 'ANY';
$code = preg_replace('@\\\|\/@i', "_", $code);
$cmd = $genbarcode_loc.' "'.$code."\" \"".strtoupper($encoding)."\"";
$fp = popen($cmd, 'r');
if ($fp) {
    $bars = fgets($fp, 1024);
    $text = fgets($fp, 1024);
    $encoding = fgets($fp, 1024);
    pclose($fp);
} 
else {
    return false;
}
$ret = array(
    'encoding' => trim($encoding),
    'bars' => trim($bars),
    'text' => trim($text)
    );
if (!$ret['encoding']) return false;
if (!$ret['bars']) return false;
if (!$ret['text']) return false;
return $ret;
```

}

[Blank barcode generated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wuzyt.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should add nix/genbarcode plugin to your CentOS server. then it will be working fine.
Run the following command :

```
dhclient

yum update

curl https://nixos.org/nix/install | sh

rpm -ivh epel-release*rpm
```